# Convert String into Arithmetic Operator

Tags: string, math, casting, lua, operator-keyword

I've an array containing math operators. At some point in my Lua app, I must extract one of those operators and perform a real operation (not a concatenation of strings). The extraction part is very clear to me, but I really don't know how to convert the string to an arithmetic operator to perform a calculation. I need something like this (this is JavaScript) but in Lua:

```
var execute = {
    '+': function (x, y) { return x + y },
    '-': function (x, y) { return x - y }
}​​​​​​​;

execute['+'](2, 2) == 4;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are very close:

```
local execute = {
  ['+'] = function (x, y) return x + y end,
  ['-'] = function (x, y) return x - y end,
}
print(execute['+'](2, 2) == 4)
```